# Error cannot convert from 'GameLibrary.GamePlayLoader2.WinningLinesParent' to 'int'

Tags: c#

This is where im having coversion error. new WinningLinesParent(0, num, num2, list, list2)

```
    public WinningLinesParent(int id, int rowForCol_0, int rowForCol_1, List<int> linesSharedByFirst2Rows, List<int> linesSharedByFirst3Rows)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.RowForCol_0 = rowForCol_0;
        this.RowForCol_1 = rowForCol_1;
        this.LinesSharedByFirst2Rows = linesSharedByFirst2Rows;
        this.LinesSharedByFirst3Rows = linesSharedByFirst3Rows;
    }

    protected void buildWinningLineParents()
    {
        List<int> list2;
        int num = 0;
        int num2 = 0;
        List<int> list = new List<int> { 2, 13, 0x15, 0x16 };
        list2 = new List<int> {
            13,
            0x16,
            new WinningLinesParent(0, num, num2, list, list2)
        };
     }
```

Comment: Your code as is makes no sense - you can't put a `WinningLinesParent` into a `List<int>` - what did you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Well you're trying to add a `WinningLinesParent` to a `List<int>`. How do you *expect* that to work?

A `List<int>` can only contain integers. I strongly suspect you shouldn't be building a `List<int>`, if you want something which can contain a `WinningLinesParent`.

Also in common with your previous posts, you're declaring a variable before it's initialized for no good reason, and also trying to use that variable *before* it's assigned (using `list2` as an argument to the `WinningLinesParent` constructor).

Between this and your previous posts, I seriously suggest you take a step back and think about what you're trying to achieve and make sure you understand what `List<T>` is used for.

Answer (score 0):

The List of type int cannot add a WinningLinesParent to its elements (which is not of type int), so the error is quite normal.